# How to write this query (containing group by and join in subquery) in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two models Channel and Program. The relationship is : A Channel has many Programs.

Now I intend to show how many programs a specific channel has in my view.

So I come up with the following SQL to fetch relevant data.

`SELECT channels.channel_id, channels.name, num_of_programs
  FROM channels
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT p.channel_id cid, COUNT(*) num_of_programs
    FROM programs p, channels c
    WHERE p.channel_id = c.channel_id
    GROUP BY p.channel_id
  ) v
  ON channels.channel_id = v.cid;`

How to write this query in Laravel Eloquent?

By the way, are there better,more efficient SQL to accomplish my task?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have num_of_programs colume in you channels table?

Comment: No. That's why I have to use count() and group by in my subquery to get that column.

Comment: You don't need the subquery to do that. You can do the same with the join and group by without the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many possibilities. That's one:

```
    DB::table('channels')
        ->join('programs', 'channels.id', '=', 'programs.channel_id')
        ->select('channels.id', 'channles.name', DB::raw('count(programs.id) as num_of_programs'))
        ->groupBy('channels.id', 'channels.name')
        ->get();
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: As you advised, I complicated the query. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the join and group by, and i am not familiar with  Laravel Eloquent.
You can try with this

```
    SELECT c.channel_id,c.name,COUNT(p.program_id)
    FROM channels c 
    LEFT JOIN  programs p ON p.channel_id = c.channel_id
    GROUP BY p.channel_id;
```

Comment: Yeah, I complicated the query. I simplified it in the same way you did. Thank you anyway. :)